# Does Entity Framework 6 or Core support Oracle 10.2g

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, oracle10g

I am using oracle 10.2g as it's my organization database version now
and I want to ask
Does Entity Framework Core or 6 support Oracle 10.2g ?

if it not what the version of Entity Framework core or not core support Oracle 10.2g

Comment: [Database Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Comment: What about EF6 is it support Oracle 10.2g

Comment: You needs to add corresponding package in the link which `Alexander Petrov` offered above.

Comment: what do you mean by the corresponding package because the link offers only Devart as a solution and I am asking about EF6